# Want to simplify the REGEXP_SUBSTR() in oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have two REGEXP_SUBSTR statements and looking to simplify those further.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Node-323401:BellUser:Job-221429','[^ :]+',1,2)FROM DUAL;

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('WebWORKS3:BellUser','[^ :]+',1,2)FROM DUAL;
```

For both of these I get the expected output : BellUser. which is satisfactory.

I need a way to simplify the regular expression in a way to get the BellUSer if the expression changes to 'BellUser:Job-221429' or'Node:323401:BellUser:Job-221429' or 'Web:WORKS3:BellUser' or anything else.

Comment: It is already very simple

Comment: You never explained rules which lead from source to target. How do you know that  "BellUser" is what you need? Sometimes it is the first substring, sometimes the third ... but - what makes it so *special*?

Comment: You want to extract `BellUser`, but already given as a searching condition as `BellUser`. I think that seems has no sense, doesn't that..?

Comment: Lets say if there is a space between Bell and user : like SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('WebWORKS3:Bell User','[^ :]+',1,2)FROM DUAL; -- i get the output as Bell. i would need user as well

Comment: I want a generic query to show the output as 'BellUser' as well as 'Bell User' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to resolve only space issue below query will help with case statement but as all stated in comments if position of 'BellUser' keep changing this query will not work and it doesn't make sense

```
select CASE WHEN  REGEXP_COUNT('WebWORKS3:Bell User', ' ', 1, 'i')= 0 THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR ('WebWORKS3:Bell User','[^ :]+',1,2) 
       ELSE    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('WebWORKS3:Bell User','[^ :]+',1,2) ||' '|| REGEXP_SUBSTR ('WebWORKS3:Bell User','[^ ]+',1,2) END from dual;
```